# How to change or set cache key based on browser user agent?

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, varnish, optimization, fastly

Is it possible to maintain separate caches in Varnish or Fastly for desktop and mobile users?
I am trying to load only the required items in the mobile devices instead of loading all CSS files, blocks, a few hidden elements using user agents.

Looking forward to suggestions.

Comment: Hope this post will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/267832/31910

Comment: @ShoaibMunir Got it, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Don't try this in production!

In theory it is possible to do the following:

```
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.User-Agent);
}
```

Although this will create a cache variation per `User-Agent` value, I would **NEVER** recommend using this: there are just too many different kind of `User-Agent` values and it will result in a terrible hit rate.

### Community-maintained device detection VCL

There's a [commmunity-maintained device detection VCL file](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-devicedetect) that does some basic checks and sets a `X-UA-Device` header containing the type of device.

Here's how you can use it:

```
include "devicedetect.vcl";

sub vcl_recv {
    call devicedetect;
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if(req.http.X-UA-Device ~ "mobile") {
        hash_data("mobile");
    } elseif(req.http.X-UA-Device ~ "tablet") {
        hash_data("tablet");
    } elseif(req.http.X-UA-Device ~ "pc") {
        hash_data("pc");
    } else {
        hash_data("other");
    }
}
```

This is a very static approach and depends on updates of the `devicedetect.vcl` file. It works in most cases, but is not as good as [Device Atlas](https://deviceatlas.com/).

### Device Atlas support

If you want a very reliable way to detect devices, you can use Device Atlas.

Varnish Enterprise has the `vmod_deviceatlas` module that reads the Device Atlas JSON files and provides a clean API. See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/deviceatlas/ for more information.

> Both Device Atlas and Varnish Enterprise are commercial solutions and require a license.